# ValueError: I/O operation

Tags: python-2.7

I see following error when executing this python code. What is issue here?
I have used "sys.stdout.close()" still I see these errors.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
a = [ 10, 12, 13, 14]
sys.stdout=open("file.txt","w")
print("++++++++")
print("***xyz***")
print("++++++++")
sys.stdout.close()
for i in a:
    print i
```

## Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test3.py", line 10, in <module>
    print i
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to stdout (your file) after closing it. At line 8 you close the file, and at line 10 you call `print`.

If you want to write the list `a` to the file you should close it after the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks!  After closing the file, I want  later part of the code to print in the terminal. is that possible?

Comment: The original stdout can be accessed with `sys.__stdout__`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `with open` because you don't have to worry about closing it. If your list needs to be a list then consider pickling it instead of writing it to a file. Pickling serializes your data.

```
#!python3

# import module
from os import system
import pickle
# clear the screan
system('cls')

a = [ 10, 12, 13, 14]

# write a list to file, but it has to be written as a string
with open('file.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(str(a))

# when you open your file up, the data is a string
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for item in fp:
        print(item)
        print(type(item))

# if you want to retain your data as a list, then pickle it
output = open('file.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(a, output)
output.close()

# open up a pickled file
pkl_file = open('file.pkl', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(pkl_file)
print(data)
print(type(data))
pkl_file.close()
```